# Creating A Printable Employee Information List

Tags: active-directory

I am trying to create a nice, printable contact information list or page that keeps itself up to date as our Active Directory changes. I thought maybe InfoPath was a good direction, but I'm struggling to make anything work.

Basically I just need this contacts list/page to use the AD fields (Display Name, Title, etc) of my choice and the AD User Groups of my choice (Include all users from location 1, 2, etc).

People Search and My sites are nice, but they don't provide anything someone can print off.

Comment: Is this for a 'plant floor' situation where people need access to the info without necessarily having access to a computer?

Comment: Yep, that is pretty much the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing that comes to mind is to create a separate [customized People Search results](http://blog.vgrem.com/2013/02/26/customizing-search-results-sharepoint-2010-people-search-results-custom-sorting-using-xslt/) page that you can link to manually and pass whatever parameters you want (like Dept, location).  You could then customize the XSL used in the results to render the content like a directory rather than search results.

Comment: Excellent idea!